# Terraform: Upload File to Windows AMI with Private IP

Tags: terraform, winrm

I am trying to upload a file to my Windows Server VM running on EC2 that does not have a public IP address. Here is my terraform resource that describes the instance.

```
resource "aws_instance" "windows" {
  count                  = 1
  ami                    = "${var.ami_id}"
  instance_type          = "${var.instance_type}"
  subnet_id              = "${module.vpc.internal_subnets[0]}"
  user_data              = "<powershell>net user Administrator thisIsJustTemporary!</powershell>"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.winrm.id}", "${module.security_groups.internal_rdp}", "${module.security_groups.allow_outbound}"]
  key_name               = "${var.key_name}"

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./my-script.ps1"
    destination = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\connect-slave.ps1"

  #   connection {
  #     type     = "winrm"
  #     user     = "Administrator"
  #     password = "thisIsJustTemporary!"

  #     bastion_host        = "${module.bastion.external_ip}"
  #     bastion_private_key = "${file(var.ssh_private_key_path)}"
  #     bastion_user        = "ubuntu"
  #   }
  }

  tags {
    Name               = "${var.name}-windows-${count.index+1}"
  }
}
```

I can't seem to find any documentation about how to use WinRM through a bastion host though. WinRM *is* properly set up because this all works fine when I launch the instance in an public subnet and connect directly to the instance.

Or, is there a way to ssh into Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a currently unsupported feature. You can track the progress of the feature request [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/13083).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get your script by leveraging user-data. For example, you could host your connect-slave.ps1 script on an S3 bucket, then use user-data to download your script in the right location.